# laravel group by date in join query to find sum of values

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am looking for laravel developer to solve a simple issue. I have 3 tables that I am joining to get data. Model data is like this:

```
date | order number | amount
```

I need to group by date and find the sum of amount. Like this:

```
date        | order number      | amount 
12/06/2022  |  ask20            |   150
12/06/2022  |  ask20            |   50
13/06/2022  |  ask21            |   120
15/06/2022  |  ask20            |   110
15/06/2022  |  ask23            |   10
16/06/2022  |  ask20            |   30
```

Now, I need to group by date to get the value like this:

```
date        | order number      | amount 
12/06/2022  |  ask20            |   200 (added value)
13/06/2022  |  ask21            |   120
15/06/2022  |  ask20            |   110 (not added as the order number is different)
15/06/2022  |  ask23            |   10
16/06/2022  |  ask20            |   30
```

Remember, I am getting this data by joining 3 tables, Can anyone help solve this?

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a simple SUM function -

```
SELECT date, order_number, SUM(amount)
  FROM <YOUR BIGGER QUERY..>
 GROUP BY date, order_number
```